# insert text into <textarea>

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to insert some text in a file into `<textarea></textarea>` in an html file when one clicks a link in a different html page.

html1.html:

```
<a href="#" id="link">click to add text</a>
```

html2.html:

```
<form action="...">
   <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
</form>
```

js:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
   window.location = "./html2.html";
   var text = $("#some_id").text();
   $("#txt").val(text)
});
```

Comment: Is `some_id` in html1 or html2?

Comment: window.location = "./html2.html"; will immediately load a new page, overwriting the current page. Therefore the rest of the script won't run.

Comment: what's your ultimate goal here? maybe you don't see it working because it actualy gets you to html2.html ?

Comment: What does that jQuery function do? It looks like that it's doing something so **messy**. Redirecting the page first using `window.location` and then dealing the *TextArea*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you migrate to the new page any further JS execution is lost.  You'd have to do something like this, passing the text to the new page in a query string variable:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
   var encodedText = encodeURIComponent($("#some_id").text());
   window.location = "./html2.html?txt=" + encodedText;
});
```

And have some code like this on your `html2.html` page:

```
var capturedText = window.location.search.match(/(\?|&)txt=(.*?)(&|$)/);
capturedText = capturedText ? decodeURIComponent(capturedText[2]) : '';
$("#txt").val(capturedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `some_id` is in `html2.html`, then it's easy: Have the JavaScript in html2.html fill in the text

```
$("#txt").val($("#some_id").text());
```

If `some_id` is in `html1.html`, you should send the value to the server and fill in the textarea on the server-side. In the event that this is unnecessarily complicated or unfeasible, you can pass the text in a number of different ways, the most common being:

- in the URL `html2.html?text="my text"`
- in a cookie (not recommended in most cases)

If you do it via URL, simply extract the text from the URL in the JavaScript on `html2.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you run "window.location", the new page will start loading, and the script will stop executing.

Additionally, you can't modify elements on the future page.

Your best shot is loading `html2.html#someTextHere`, and on `html2.html` copy the text from the hash into the textarea.